# Print the column name instead of the number data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

my data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), col1 = c(9, 
9.05, 7.15, 7.21, 7.34, 8.12, 7.5, 7.84, 7.8, 7.52, 8.84, 6.98, 
6.1, 6.89, 6.5, 7.5, 7.8, 5.5, 6.61, 7.65, 7.68,8.0,9.0), col2 = c(11L, 
11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L,3L,4L), col3 = c(7L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 
5L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 2L,5L,6L), 
    col4 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 
    11L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 11L,13L,12L), col5 = c(11L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 
    8L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L,4L,5L)), .Names = c("group", "col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

function:

```
comb <- list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5), c(4, 6))

test.fun <- function(dat) { 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(comb, function(x) {
    SUM <- dat[[x[1]]]+dat[[x[2]]]
    data.frame(NAME = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]),
                SUM)
   
  }))
}

result <- purrr::map_df(split(data, data$group), test.fun, .id = 'Group')
```

In the `NAME` column, I have the names of a combination of columns displayed, I would like to see its name there instead of the column number

For example:

```
GROUP col1 GROUP col3
...
```

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `comb` from column numbers to column names.

```
comb <- list(c('col1', 'col3'), c('col2', 'col4'), c('col3', 'col5'))
```

When you run your code you'll get column names instead of numbers.

```
test.fun <- function(dat) { 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(comb, function(x) {
    SUM <- dat[[x[1]]]+dat[[x[2]]]
    data.frame(NAME = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]),
               SUM)
    
  }))
}

result <- purrr::map_df(split(data, data$group), test.fun, .id = 'Group')

result

#   Group                     NAME   SUM
#1      1 Group col1 by Group col3 16.00
#2      1 Group col1 by Group col3 20.05
#3      1 Group col1 by Group col3 10.15
#4      1 Group col1 by Group col3 14.21
#5      1 Group col1 by Group col3 18.34
#6      1 Group col1 by Group col3 10.12
#7      1 Group col1 by Group col3 18.50
#8      1 Group col1 by Group col3 12.84
#9      1 Group col2 by Group col4 22.00
#...
#...
```

---

To get column name from number use this function.

```
test.fun <- function(dat) { 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(comb, function(x) {
    x <- names(dat)[x]
    SUM <- dat[[x[1]]]+dat[[x[2]]]
    data.frame(NAME = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]),
               SUM)
    
  }))
}
```

Comment: I understand this, you wrote to me about it. when I pass the column numbers to the function in the output I want to get their name

Comment: See the updated answer to get name when passing number to the function.